# IEEEtran and subfig - why is there no text on the second column

Tags: subfloats, ieeetran

```
\documentclass[conference, a4paper, twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\usepackage[caption=false, font=normalsize, labelfont=sf, textfont=sf]{subfig}

%\usepackage[caption=false, font=footnotesize]{subfig}



\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

%\onecolumn
\title{aAAA\\
{
}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{dbh}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{} \\
\textit{}\\
}}


\maketitle
\raggedbottom
\begin{abstract}
test
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
s
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction} 




\section{Numerical Results}
\label{NumericalResults}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=21pc, height=8pc]{example-image}} \\
    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=21pc, height=8pc]{example-image}}\\
    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=21pc, height=8pc]{example-image}}\\
    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=21pc, height=9pc]{example-image}}\\
    \caption{.}
    \label{plot1}
\end{figure}

\blindtext



\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=21pc, height=8pc]{example-image}} \\
    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=21pc, height=8pc]{example-image}}
    \caption{.}
    \label{plot2}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext



\vspace{12pt}

\end{document}
```

Why is there no text on the second coulum? The width is okay and is working fine on other figures. In the same document is another subfloat figure and there its working in the desired manner. I have no idea why on the second subfloat figure this problem takes place. Any recommendation?

[image]

Comment: please always provide a complete small document,  not a code fragment,  the code you post is missing `\begin{document}` and can not be used to debug the issue. you can use `example-image` as the image in your test file as that is available for this kind of test

Comment: you get  `LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 194.8038pt on input line 72.`  so the figure is far too large to fit on a page,

Comment: unrelated to the question but you shouldn't use fixltx2e unless you have a very old (pre 2015) latex, you don't need textcomp if you have a 2020 latex release, you probably shouldn't load multicol (you are using standard twocolumn mode, you are specifying amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts twice, mathtools includes amsmath, so you actually just need amssymb and mathtools. And I wouldn't use commath

Comment: Okay i solved the problem. Dont use \usepackage{stfloats}. If i remove this command, the desired result will take place. Thank you for your help David. Best Wishes

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Your figure is far too large to fit on the page as LaTeX warns

```
LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 194.8038pt on input line 72
```

and the blank column is a side effect of latex trying and failing to find something that fits.

Here you do not really want floats anyway as the section is a sequence of images that you do not want to float off, so here I remove the figure environment which allows column and page breaking between each image. Locally I set `\@captype` to figure so that you can still have captions.

```
\documentclass[conference, a4paper, twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage[caption=false, font=normalsize, labelfont=sf, textfont=sf]{subfig}

%\usepackage[caption=false, font=footnotesize]{subfig}



\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

%\onecolumn
\title{aAAA\\
{
}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{dbh}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{} \\
\textit{}\\
}}

%\begin{multicols}{2}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
test
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
s
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction} 




\section{Numerical Results}
\label{NumericalResults}

{\centering
\makeatletter\def\@captype{figure}\raggedbottom

    \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=21pc]{example-image}\label{cfgfdghfgcfdgcfga}} 


    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=21pc]{example-image}\label{cfgfdghfgcfdgcfgb}}


    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=21pc]{example-image}\label{cfgfdghfgcfdgcfgb}}


    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=21pc]{example-image}\label{cfgfdghfgcfdgcfgb}}



    %\subfloat[c]{\includegraphics[width=21pc]{Schritt}\label{cfgfdghfgcfdgcfgc} }
    \caption{.}
    \label{plot2}

    \centering
    \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=21pc]{example-image}\label{cfgfdghfgcfdgcfga}} 


    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=21pc]{example-image}\label{cfgfdghfgcfdgcfgb}}


    %\subfloat[c]{\includegraphics[width=21pc]{Schritt}\label{cfgfdghfgcfdgcfgc} }
    \caption{.}
    \label{plot2}


}

LaTeX ist ein Textsatzsystem. Bei LaTex schreibt man den Quellcode in reinem Text 
(ähnlich einer Programmiersprache) in einem beliebigen Editor und lässt diesen Text 
dann durch das Programm latex kompilieren. Das Ergebnis ist eine DVI-Datei (Device 
Independent = Geräte unabhängig), die dann in weitere, gängige Formate wie zum Beispiel 
Postscript und PDF konvertiert werden kann. Alternativ kann man auch gleich pdflatex statt 
latex verwenden, dann generiert man aus dem LaTex -Quellcode direkt eine PDF-Datei. 
Wozu der Umweg? Durch diese Umwege kann ein nur einmal geschriebenes Dokument in 
verschiedenste, völlig andere Dokumente ohne Mehraufwand exportiert werden.LaTeX ist ein Textsatzsystem. Bei LaTex schreibt man den Quellcode in reinem Text 
(ähnlich einer Programmiersprache) in einem beliebigen Editor und lässt diesen Text 
dann durch das Programm latex kompilieren. Das Ergebnis ist eine DVI-Datei (Device 
Independent = Geräte unabhängig), die dann in weitere, gängige Formate wie zum Beispiel 
Postscript und PDF konvertiert werden kann. Alternativ kann man auch gleich pdflatex statt 
latex verwenden, dann generiert man aus dem LaTex -Quellcode direkt eine PDF-Datei. 
LaTeX ist ein Textsatzsystem. Bei LaTex schreibt man den Quellcode in reinem Text 
(ähnlich einer Programmiersprache) in einem beliebigen Editor und lässt diesen Text 
dann durch das Programm latex kompilieren. Das Ergebnis ist eine DVI-Datei (Device 
Independent = Geräte unabhängig), die dann in weitere, gängige Formate wie zum Beispiel 
Postscript und PDF konvertiert werden kann. Alternativ kann man auch gleich pdflatex statt 
latex verwenden, dann generiert man aus dem LaTex -Quellcode direkt eine PDF-Datei. 
Wozu der Umweg? Durch diese Umwege kann ein nur einmal geschriebenes Dokument in 
verschiedenste, völlig andere Dokumente ohne Mehraufwand exportiert werden.LaTeX ist ein Textsatzsystem. Bei LaTex schreibt man den Quellcode in reinem Text 
(ähnlich einer Programmiersprache) in einem beliebigen Editor und lässt diesen Text 
dann durch das Programm latex kompilieren. Das Ergebnis ist eine DVI-Datei (Device 
Independent = Geräte unabhängig), die dann in weitere, gängige Formate wie zum Beispiel 
Postscript und PDF konvertiert werden kann. Alternativ kann man auch gleich pdflatex statt 
latex verwenden, dann generiert man aus dem LaTex -Quellcode direkt eine PDF-Datei. 









\section{Conclusion}
\label{Conclusion}


\vspace{12pt}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help David! I fixed the size problem, but it seems it doesnt fit. It seems that you can only use one figure that include the subfloat command.

```
\documentclass[conference, a4paper, twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\usepackage[caption=false, font=normalsize, labelfont=sf, textfont=sf]{subfig}

%\usepackage[caption=false, font=footnotesize]{subfig}



\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

%\onecolumn
\title{aAAA\\
{
}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{dbh}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{} \\
\textit{}\\
}}

%\begin{multicols}{2}
\maketitle
\raggedbottom
\begin{abstract}
test
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
s
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction} 




\section{Numerical Results}
\label{NumericalResults}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=21pc, height=8pc]{example-image}} \\
    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=21pc, height=8pc]{example-image}}\\
    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=21pc, height=8pc]{example-image}}\\
    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=21pc, height=8pc]{example-image}}\\
    \caption{.}
    \label{plot1}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=21pc, height=8pc]{example-image}} \\
    \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=21pc, height=8pc]{example-image}}\\
    %\subfloat[c]{\includegraphics[width=21pc]{Schritt}\label{cfgfdghfgcfdgcfgc} }
    \caption{.}
    \label{plot2}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext


\section{Conclusion}
\label{Conclusion}


\vspace{12pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please don't use the answer posts for non-answers, it messes up the question-answer format of the site for futile readers. You can edit your question to clarify it, or ask a new question, or (once you get a few points) leave a comment under an answer

Comment: you haven't used any of the code I suggested in my answer so I'm not sure what I can say to this further question other than refer you to my existing answer.

Comment: Oh, iam sorry. Yes because it don’t place the subfloats in one column rather it splits the figure over both columns. The problem also occurs with normal figures but only after i once used the subfloat command.

Comment: it's nothing to do with subfloat, it's just that you have too much text in the figure to fit on a column.

Comment: Too much text in the figure? Do you mean caption text? I updated my original question to be more precise.

Comment: no too much of anything, text images etc, the figure has to fit on the page...

Comment: But now there is no critical item involved but the problem stays the same. Please check out my updated original post.

Comment: after your edit your question will not make sense at all for future readers as the code shown now has no problem, there is no blank column. Please don't edit questions in that way.